# How to use java 8 streams to get more readability and performance to this code

Tags: java, stream

I got a forms list, and it has a tags list. I received from my front end app an array of tags (`String`), gotta filter these forms by these tags.

```
forms.forEach(form -> {
    br.com.softplan.ungp.dynamic.form.api.model.Form formJson = new Gson()
            .fromJson(form.getSchema(), br.com.softplan.ungp.dynamic.form.api.model.Form.class);

    tags.forEach(tag -> formJson.getTags().forEach(formTag -> {
        if (tag.toUpperCase().equals(formTag.getText().toUpperCase())) {
            if (map.containsKey(tag)) {
                List<FormSummary> list = new ArrayList<>(map.get(tag));
                list.add(new FormSummary(form.getId(), form.getName()));
                map.put(tag,list);
            } else {
                map.put(tag, Collections.singletonList(new FormSummary(form.getId(), form.getName())));
            }
        }
    }));
});
```

This code is already working as expected. I just want to improve it, writing less code using Java utilities.

What I was trying to do is to map all the result inside a map into its own iteration, using `stream.map()` or the `Collectors.toMap()`, but couldn't achieve what I wanted.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not easy to understand. However, you might replace the inner if-else construct with

```
map.computeIfAbsent(tag, t -> new ArrayList<>())
   .add(new FormSummary(form.getId(), form.getName()));
```

for brevity.

Note that the nested `forEach` will probably give you \$O(|\mathrm{forms}| \cdot |\mathrm{tags}|)\$ time complexity which could be a problem if `forms` or `tags` contains many elements.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this computeIfAbsent method, really helped. About the complexity, I know, this is not the way it's gonna be, just a temporary solution. I reorganized my code, it's more readable now.